# How can I solve the following issue in python AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_dict'?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am facing issue in the below code in pandas python. When I run the following cell, I did not face any issue but when I run the next cell The error shows up:

```
def build_anonymized_dataset(df, partitions, feature_columns, sensitive_column, max_partitions=None):
    aggregations = {}
    for column in feature_columns:
        if column in categorical:
            aggregations[column] = agg_categorical_column
        else:
            aggregations[column] = agg_numerical_column
    rows = []
    for i, partition in enumerate(partitions):
        if i % 100 == 1:
            print("Finished {} partitions...".format(i))
        if max_partitions is not None and i > max_partitions:
            break
        grouped_columns = df.loc[partition].agg(aggregations, squeeze=False)
        sensitive_counts = df.loc[partition].groupby(sensitive_column).agg({sensitive_column : 'count'})
        values = grouped_columns.iloc[0].to_dict().items()
        for sensitive_value, count in sensitive_counts[sensitive_column].items():
            if count == 0:
                continue
            values.update({
                sensitive_column : sensitive_value,
                'count' : count,

            })
            rows.append(values.copy())
    return pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

But when I run the following cell, I am facing error related to the previous cell. I do not understand what is this error and how can solve it.

```
dfn = build_anonymized_dataset(df, finished_partitions, feature_columns, sensitive_column)
```

the following  error appear:

```
  14 grouped_columns = df.loc[partition].agg(aggregations, squeeze=False)
     15 sensitive_counts = df.loc[partition].groupby(sensitive_column).agg({sensitive_column : 'count'})
---> 16 values = grouped_columns.iloc[0].to_dict().items()
     17 for sensitive_value, count in sensitive_counts[sensitive_column].items():
     18     if count == 0:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_dict'
```

Comment: A `pandas` Series or DataFrame has a `to_dict` method.  A list does not.  That means `grouped_columns.iloc[0]` must be a list; what did you expect it to be?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).